# Class Template SFINAE via Inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, sfinae

The `s1` class template specialisation below only allows instantiations of `s1` when using integral type template arguments.

```
template <typename, typename = void>
  struct s1;

template <typename T>
struct s1<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>> { };
```

The following class template, `s2`, is similar; though it conditionally inherits privately from a trivial base class. What are the differences in functionality between `s1` and `s2`?

```
struct Base { };

template <typename T>
struct s2 : private std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value,Base> { };
```

Comment: And if `T` is not integral, what do you think `s2` will  derive from?

Comment: If you make s2 derive privately from Base then I think for all intents and purposes they are equivalent.

Comment: I've updated `s2` to inherit privately as suggested by @RichardHodges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `s1` you can extend it with new specializations that cover more cases in distributed bits of code.  SFINAE would kick in, and so long as only one specialization was valid, it would be chosen.

The expression tested in such specializations is arbitrary.

I could create an `s1` specialization that accepts when `T` is floating point, or a complex type, or is an array.

For `s2`, only things that template pattern matching can prefer to a bare `T` can be used to create further matching specializations.  There is no way to create an `s2` specialization that accepts any floating point types, for example, but I could create one that accepts any pointers.

Comment: Thanks. What I'm interested in is the difference in functionality between the pair - as they are.

Comment: @user as they are neither template does anything.  Well I guess one could measure how long it takes them to compile.  They do behave differently with respect to other code that can use them, which is what I tried to answer.  They also behave the same with respect to some other code that can use them.  If you have a particular *kind* of use restrictions in mind that you mean by "as they are" that you care about, it would help to be explicit.  I mean, does passing them as template template arguments count?

Comment: Fair point. Yes, template template arguments would count. I assume the idea that only `s1` can take two template arguments relates to this (a clear difference in functionality). For example `s1<int,void>`. Thank you for the answer.